# Determine winner from access n element from array of array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have an array of arrays looking like this...

```
[['Abradolf Lincler', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Rick Sanchez', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Rick Sanchez', 4, 3], ['Rick Sanchez', 4, 3], ['Tophat Jones', 4, 3], ['Xenon Bloom', 4, 4], ['Jerry Smith', 4, 4], ['Xenon Bloom', 4, 4], ['Jerry Smith', 4, 4], ['Xenon Bloom', 4, 4], ['Xenon Bloom', 4, 4], ['Jerry Smith', 4, 4], ['Jerry Smith', 4, 4], ['Xenon Bloom', 4, 4], ['Jerry Smith', 4, 4], ['Jerry Smith', 4, 4], ['Jerry Smith', 4, 4], ['Summer Smith', 4, 4], ['Summer Smith', 4, 4], ['Summer Smith', 4, 4]]
```

- 0<sup>th</sup> element - Player name
- 1<sup>st</sup> element - Player score
- 2<sup>nd</sup> element - Player group

I had it so player scores are combined, like this...

```
grouped_scores = {}
for name, score, group_number in scores:
    if name not in grouped_scores:
        grouped_scores[name] = score
    else:
        grouped_scores[name] += score
```

But I now I also want to be able to look at each group number and be able to output the winner of each group based on score. Not sure how to do that.
I tried doing another for loop inside my current above code but that doesn't work. Please help

Comment: If you use a Counter https://stackoverflow.com/a/53291310/174728, you can use `result.most_common(1)`. If you do it your way, you can use `max(grouped_scores, key=grouped_scores.get)`